# Setup collection of objects to be added in Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I would like to keep track of items added in my unit test. I've setup my collection like so:

```
var items = new List<IItem>();
var mock = new Mock<IItem>();
mockCollection.Setup(x => x.AddNew()).Returns(() =>
{
    mock.SetupAllProperties();
    return mock.Object;
}).Callback(() =>
{
    items.Add(mock.Object);
});
```

This works and new items are added to list, however, this is problematic because whenever **AddNew()** method is called, all the properties of the previous "mock" object get replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the AddNew method does not have a parameter but you added a parameter to the callback ( where is that parameter coming from???). Instead do try the following

```
Mock<IItem> mock=null;
var items = new List<IItem>();
mockCollection.Setup(x => x.AddNew()).Returns(() =>
{
    mock = new Mock<IItem>();
    mockShipment.SetupAllProperties();
    return mock.Object;
}).Callback(()=>
{
    items.Add(mock.Object);
});
```